# Java JFrame won't show up after using .setVisible(true) after being invisible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'll start explaining from the bottom to top, so you will actually understand what I was trying to do, and understand my code better.

I am creating a library, that let's you capture an area, whether if the capture is a gif animation or an image. After capturing is finished, the library will return an object that contains `ByteArrayInputStream` and util methods like `createImage` etc.

While reading this, you can have access to the library here: https://github.com/BenBeri/WiseCapturer/

Now this is a dummy example on how my library works:

Your application creates an instance of bootstrap with the capturer class, and begins a capture:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
            b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage())));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The listener will return `CapturedImage` which you can use to do whatever you wish to.
Now with this example, this should let you capture twice, once and again after you're done, and once it's done, it will show the 2nd capture in a JFrame window.

Now I am not talking about this JFrame.

The problem only occurs with `ScreeenshotCapturer`, it will work fine with `GifCapturer` instance.

### The problem

After finishing the first capture, the second capture JFrame transparent window will not come up, I don't see it in the windows toolbar, nor anywhere, but the application still runs.

However, as I said it does work if I use GifCapturer instance.

Now let's debug how my library works:

Bootstrap constructor:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap consturctor, let it bootstrap!
 * @param c
 *              Capturer instance
 * @throws AWTException
 */
public Bootstrap(Capturer c) throws AWTException {
    this.capturer = c;
}
```

Now the Capturer class initializes, it's the abstract class, same constructor for all capturers:

```
public Capturer() throws AWTException {
    this.camera = new CaptureCamera(this);
}
```

This creates a new capture camera, which is where I am having the problem.
The purpose of CaptureCamera is to have the whole JFrame, transparent sized the same as my screen, and contain in it the JPanel that is responsible to do the selection rectangle drawing.

The constructor of it:

```
public CaptureCamera(Capturer c) throws AWTException {
    this.c = c;
    this.toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    this.screen = this.toolkit.getScreenSize();
    this.robot = new Robot();
    this.selector = new SelectionCamera();

    super.setSize(this.screen);
    super.setUndecorated(true);
    super.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 1));

    // Listeners for area selection
    super.addMouseListener(new SelectionAdapter(this, this.selector));
    super.addMouseMotionListener(new SelectionMotion(this, this.selector));

    super.add(this.selector);
}
```

Okay, now let's take a look at how the capturing begins.

the `beginCapture` method in bootstrap:

```
/**
 * Starts capturing the screen, sends back a callback event with the
 * captured file.
 * 
 * The system saves a temporary file to send the file.
 * @param c
 *          Callback instance
 */
public void beginCapture(ScreenCaptureCallback c) {
    this.capturer.setCallback(c);
    this.capturer.beginSelection();
}
```

`setCallback` is not really important for this problem, so `beginSelection` method:

**The same for all capturers**

```
@Override
public void beginSelection() {
    super.init();
    this.setHotkeys();
    super.getCamera().startSelection();
}
```

startSelection method (sorry for the dumb duplicated names with the same meaning ill change later):

```
/**
 * Starts area selection event
 * @param c Capturer instance
 */
public void startSelection() {
    super.setVisible(true);
}
```

Okay, this is where it should make the JFrame visible, I've tried printing before and it showed true, but the JFrame didn't show on the second attempt.

Now the frame is visible, and the user can select an area.
once selected, the mouese adapter will execute `startCapturing` method.

`startCapturing` in **GifCapturer**:

```
@Override
public void startCapturing(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
    this.border = new GifCaptureBorder(x, y, width, height);
    this.process = new TimerCaptureProcess(this, x, y, width, height);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(this.process, 0, 600);
}
```

`startCapturing in **ScreenshotCapturer**:

```
@Override
public void startCapturing(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Robot robot = super.getCamera().getRobot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    super.disableSelectionFrame();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", stream);
        super.setCaptureResult(stream);
        super.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now in **GifCapturer** the process is longer, because it actually starts a `Timer` to take screenshots of every frame every `60ms`.

To finish capturing a gif, you click on "enter", I used [JKeyMaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster) to detect hotkeys.
after clicking "ENTER", this method will be executed in `GifCapturer`

```
public void createGif() {
    super.disableSelectionFrame();

    AnimatedGifEncoder gif = new AnimatedGifEncoder();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    gif.start(stream);
    gif.setDelay(1000);

    this.border.updateProgress(10);

    for(int i = 0; i < this.frames.size(); i++) {
        gif.addFrame(this.frames.get(i));
    }

    this.border.updateProgress(50);

    gif.finish();

    super.setCaptureResult(stream);

    this.border.updateProgress(100);

    super.finish();
    this.border.setVisible(false);
    this.border = null;
}
```

This is pretty much it, if I will use `GifCapturer` twice, everything works fine, but if I will use `ScreenshotCapturer` twice, JFrame will NOT show up on the second time!

I am not really sure why, could this be a bug in Swing? Maybe because `GifCapturer` takes longer before it makes the frame visible?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: A runnable example would be easier to diagnose. Having said that, isolate the frame into its own class, in such away that you can hide it and reshow it,test to see if the frame can be shown again without the rest of the API around it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean? the frame already has its own class.

Comment: Yes, but is the problem with who the frame is working or how it is interacting with capture API, isolate and test the code in separation and actually find where the problem actually is...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will a library jar file help debug?

Comment: What I'm asking you to do is just test the frame in isolation to determine if it's an issue with the capture (or they way you are using it) or the way you are using your frame. You could provide a runnable example of your code with which others might be able to test with, that would be helpful. Pasting snippets of code out of context makes it very difficult to make suggestions and encourages assumptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so from what I understand the problem you are having is with this code...

Basically, the WiseCapturer API allows you to "drag" transparent rectangle over the screen when you call `beginCapture`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
            b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage())));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem you're having is when `captureEnded` is called (for the outer capture), the inner capture process is not stating (and you can't "drag" the transparent selection rectangle)...

This seems to be because you are blocking whenever thread/event queue WiseCapturer is using and the `captureEnded` event as not been allowed to finish...

If I do something like...

```
try {
    final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
                            System.out.println("...");
                            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage())));
                            frame.pack();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Hello");
} catch (AWTException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which starts a new `Thread` within the outer `captureEnded` call, I can get it to work...

Also, not knowing the Thread safety rules for this API, I also used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

```
try {
    final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
                            System.out.println("...");
                            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage())));
                            frame.pack();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Hello");
} catch (AWTException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

And had it work...I'm also a little weirded out about why you would do this, but that's just me

Comment: Thanka ill try it. And what are you wirded off? The api?

Comment: Also I solved it by adding invokeLater in the beginCapture method, is that fine to do?

Comment: Without knowing the API, it's difficult to say. Personally, I'd wrap the call to beginCapture as that's the action you a trying to encapsulate, the end of the ecapture, but that's just me