# Java screenshot capture - JFrame paints old component for a second & disappears even though all components were removed & repainted

Tags: java, swing, api, user-interface

Before you read, this will be informative: [Java JFrame won't show up after using .setVisible(true) after being invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067871/java-jframe-wont-show-up-after-using-setvisibletrue-after-being-invisible)

Hello I am working on a library API that let's you capture an area of the screen, and it returns you a class that contains the `ByteArrayInputStream` and utility methods like `createBufferedImage`, `createFile`, etc.

Basically you create a Bootstrap instance, and pass the capturer type you want as a dependency (ScreenshotCapturer or GifCapturer):

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
```

And the `beginCapture` method receives an object that implements `ScreenCaptureCallback` which is the callback event that the captured result will be passed to.

This is a short background.

Now when you use the `beginCapture` method, basically what it does is creates new instance of `SelectionCamera`, this is basically the component that paints the selection area you're selecting when dragging the mouse, and updates the listeners.

once created instance, it calls `super.setVisible(true);`

After that method gets called, the frame will show up, and also show the old painted screen for like 600-500miliseconds, I am not exactly sure, but it disappears so quickly.

Take a look at this live example:

**Note use the video option, otherwise you will not see what I'm seeing as gif is too slow to show it!**

http://gyazo.com/d2f0432ada37842966b42dfd87be4240

You can see after I click Screenshot again, it shows the old selected area and disappears quickly. (by the way the frame you see in the gif is not part of the app, just dummy hello world example usage).

The process of image capture.

**Step 1**

`beginCapture` gets called:

```
public void beginCapture(final ScreenCaptureCallback c) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            capturer.setCallback(c);
            capturer.beginSelection();

        }
    });
}
```

**Step 2**

`beginSelection` gets called in the Capturer class (`ScreenshotCapturer` extends `Capturer` (abstract)

```
@Override
public void beginSelection() {
    super.init();
    this.setHotkeys();
    super.getCamera().startSelection();
}
```

**Step 3**

`CaptureCamera#startSelection()` gets called

```
public void startSelection() {
    super.getContentPane().removeAll();
    super.getContentPane().repaint();

    super.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

    this.selector = new SelectionCamera();
    this.selectionMosueAdapter.updateCamera(this.selector);
    this.selectionMouseMotion.updateCamera(this.selector);

    super.add(this.selector);

    super.setVisible(true);
    super.repaint();
    super.getContentPane().repaint();
}
```

**Step 4**

The user selects an area, and both mouse listener and mouse motion listens to it(Take a look at mouse motion):

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point dragPoint = e.getPoint();
    Point startPoint = this.selector.getStartPoint();

    int x = Math.min(startPoint.x, dragPoint.x);
    int y = Math.min(startPoint.y, dragPoint.y);
    int width = Math.max(startPoint.x - dragPoint.x, dragPoint.x - startPoint.x);
    int height = Math.max(startPoint.y - dragPoint.y, dragPoint.y - startPoint.y);

    this.selector.setCameraDimension(width, height);
    this.selector.setCoordinates(x, y);

    this.camera.repaint(); // important
}
```

***by the way `this.selector` is `SelectorCamera` which is the component that paints the selection area.***

**Step 5**

CaptureCamera#endSelection() gets called, this method gets the x,y, width, height from the selection camera and passes it to the capturer class which uses Robot to get screenshot with that rectangle, and before that it removes ALL components from the content pane, and repaints everything and then sets visibility to false.

```
public void endSelection() {
    super.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    int x = this.selector.getCameraX();
    int y = this.selector.getCameraY();
    int w = this.selector.getCameraWidth();
    int h = this.selector.getCameraHeight();

    super.getContentPane().removeAll();
    super.getContentPane().repaint();

    //super.repaint();
    super.setVisible(false);

    this.c.startCapturing(x, y, w, h);

}
```

Basically this is the last step, rest steps are unnecessary for the debugging as it only sends back the callback.

I really tried my best explaining the process of my application, I've tried figuring it out for 5 and half hours now, and no luck at all. Tried different ways, by creating new `SelectionCamera` object as you see, doesn't work.

Why is it doing this? Is it something to do with the swing core?

SelectionCamera code: https://github.com/BenBeri/WiseCapturer/blob/master/src/il/ben/wise/SelectionCamera.java

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: It "lloks" like maybe the `selector` needs to be reset...maybe... You might also like to highlight the code that is yours and the code that from the capture library...

Comment: Everythin is in the library, all off this is my code

Comment: @MadProgrammer You said that the selector needs to be reset, but how is that possible if it does that even though that I am removing that component from the JFrame, means it won't get repainted anymore or displayed?

Comment: make Frame left to be -10,000 then set visible true, add a timer 2 seconds, on timer :left to 0

Comment: @tgkprog This works, but do you have any core explanation why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this example...

```
try {
    final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new ScreenshotCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void captureEnded(CapturedImage img) {
                            System.out.println("...");
                            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage())));
                            frame.pack();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Hello");
} catch (AWTException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

I won't focus on the initialise stage of the first round, I will focus on the initialisation of the second round as this is where the problem is...

`b.beginCapture` call's `this.capturer.beginSelection();`, which calls `super.getCamera().startSelection();` which calls `setVisible(true)` (`CaptureCamera` been a `JFrame`).

This will immediately show what ever was previously displayed on the `CaptureCamera`.  It's important to note here, that no new instances of objects were created through the process...

Now, I made a lot of changes to the base testing this, but it appears that the problem is with the restoration of the frame when it's made visible for the second time.  This seems to be an issue with the transparency support of the Window as it seems to restore the last "known" state instead of repainting the window immediately...

Now, I tried clearing the `selector` before making the `CaptureCamera` invisible to no eval, as the window seems to be made invisible before the `selector` is painted.

The final solution I came up with was to call `dispose` on the `CaptureCamera`, which releases it's native peer and therefore destroys the old graphics context, forcing the frame to rebuild itself when it is made visible again.

"A" problem with this could be the fact that when all the windows are disposed (and the only running threads are daemon threads), the JVM will exit...

This was an issue during my testing as I was using a `javax.swing.Timer` to put a delay between the first and second capture process so I could see where the problem was occurring and this caused my JVM to exit (as the timer uses a daemon thread and I had no other windows open).

I got around this by creating a tiny (1x1) transparent window in the `Capturer` class, keep this in mind if the JVM exists gracefully for no reason ;)

### Side Notes...

Now, there is an issue with `SelectionCamera` (which extends `JPanel`), it is opaque, but is using a transparent background, this is incredibly dangerous as Swing only knows how to deal with opaque or fully transparent components.

```
public SelectionCamera() {
    super.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    super.setVisible(false);
}
```

Should be updated to something like...

```
public SelectionCamera() {
    setOpaque(false);
    //super.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    super.setVisible(false);
}
```

I'm also confused over the use of `super.xxx`, the only reason you would do this is if you had overrriden those methods and didn't want to call them at this time...In my testing, I removed all the calls to `super` where a method wasn't overridden in the current class (and I wasn't already in the overriden method)

Also, the `paintComponent` method should be calling `super.paintComponent`

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f));
    g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Comment: Take a read here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/251328/java-and-rest-oop-languages-when-to-use-super-or-this-keywords & Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Make Frame left to be -10,000 then set visible true, add a timer 2 seconds (try lower to 25-100 milliseconds, just to give it sligth pause to invalidate content) , on timer :left to 0 . I think it works due to caching & double buffereing. Frame shows what it had in buffer, buffer points to old image due to caching/ lazy repaint.

---

Alternative : 
Maybe a repaint or invalidate before your show would work too, and don't need to do the left -10,000. I dont work much with ui-swing, just a but years back and remember some strange things like this.

Comment: Yes it's a solution, but a very horrible solution for my library, considering the user clicks on capture button, and needs to wait 2 seconds, yet he doesn't know he needs to, he will try to attempt selecting and will lose focus from the frame that takes care of the area selection. For that i thought of adding a cursor.WAIT but I still can't do that because the frame is -10,000 on the X-asis. I thought of making a temp jframe with the same size on 0,0 to show the please wait message or cursor, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Did you try invalidate and repaint? Maybe make it 100 milli seconds instead of 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes I've tried doing invalidate, validate & repaint both contentPane and JFrame.

Comment: Actually 100 milliseconds works perfectly, I don't even see the difference! Ill accept this anwer if I won't get any technical answers.

Comment: means leave java and go to c++ :-) not serious. that's too difficult and slow to develop. am glad 100 milliseconds worked well.

Comment: C++ is hard or java?:P